# How to fix recursion function's return value*2 error

Tags: java, swing, recursion, jbutton

I would like to fix my recurion function's return value. I set it to -1, but when I saw value, it decline like (if first value is 4, it decline like 4 3 1 -3
I would like to fix it 4 3 2 1).

I changed my return value and I used thread.sleep. I am a super newbie of programming, so I cannot find why it happen like that.

```
static int remaningchance=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("how many times will you play?"));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    buttonposition(remaningchance);
    ...
}

private static void buttonposition(int omg) {
    if(omg<0) {
        button.setVisible(false);
    }else {
        double rd= Math.random();
        int lx=(int)(rd*boxwidth);
        rd= Math.random();
        int ly=(int)(rd*(boxheight-bs));
        button.setBounds(lx,ly,bs,bs);
        frame.add(but);
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 100);;
        frame.add(label);
        label.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                remaningchance--;
                label.setText(remaningchance+"chance left");
                buttonposition(remaningchance);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I expect the remaningchance decline like 4 3 2 1 but it decline like 4 3 1 -3

Answer (score 1):

You add a new listener in every call of `buttonposition`. Each of these listeners decrements `remainingchance` when clicked. Therefore the following happens:

1. Call from `main(...)`. Button has 1 listener. `remainingchance = 4`
2. First click:  Button has 2 listeners. `remainingchance = 3`
3. Second click: Button has 4 listeners. `remainingchance = 1`
4. Third click:  Button has 8 listeners. `remainingchance = -3`

To resolve the problem you should add the listener first, instead of inside of the `buttonposition` function.

By the way: the function is not actually recursive. The listener - which contains the call to `buttonposition` is not called from within the `buttonposition`. You only tell the button what to do, when it is clicked.